# XCode - accidentally deleted build setting

Tags: xcode, buildpath

So I accidentally deleted some header search path (I think) build settings in XCode.

Now when I try to clean, I get these errors:

> Check dependencies
>
> Build setting TARGET_BUILD_DIR undefined
>
> Build setting BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR undefined

I was at this late last night for hours, and again this morning. Re-creating the project from scratch is not an option. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Do you use a source control system?

Comment: Nope... I'm reading up on git at the moment...

Comment: @trojanfoe So I had my XCode project folder synced on owncloud. I was able to restore a previous version of project.pbxproj

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to change [Per-configuration Build Products Path] from blank to `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Comment: @dotctor That's true, but this does attempt to answer a question - and if I had this problem, this answer would stand a good chance of solving it. This is not something we should be [deleting from review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10751995).